# How to UUEncode in android

Tags: java, android, uuencode

Using which libraries, I can UUENcode some binary in Android java? I just couldn't find any UUEncoder api available in java for android.

Does anybody know such an api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only libraries that I'm aware of for UUEncoding are Oracle's, which ships with Java SDK (and is not replicated in the Android SDK), and the one in Ant.

I'm guessing that you're not going to want to include the Ant library in your Android application.

I did find source for Sun/Oracle's UUEncoder at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/UUEncoder.java.html

It's GPL2 licensed, so if you feel that your software can meet the demands of that license, you could just copy the source for that one class into your application.

Failing that, you could implement the algorithm yourself.
See, for example, http://www.herongyang.com/encoding/UUEncode-Algorithm.html

Comment: Here is a library that is available under the Apache License Version 2.0: https://codeberg.org/marc.nause/uuencode

Comment: I'd like to point out that now, almost 10 years after the question was asked / answered, UUEncode / UUDecode has largely been replaced by Base-64 encoding / decoding, largely because base-64 works with any character set, while UU is character set dependent. I assume that some folks, like Petra, still have to interface with systems using UU, but in most situations, Base-64 would be preferred.